# Java - Existence of method causing program to not work correctly

Tags: java, serialization

In my Java program, I have a class called `Car`, which is `Serializable`. I have another class called `StaffCar` which is a subclass of `Car`.

Then there a class called `Fleet` which essentially stores `StaffCar` objects in `ArrayList<StaffCar> fleet`.

I then have a class `Main` which consists of the `main` method which consists of a menu and a `switch` to handle menu options.

The problem I'm having is when I add a method in `StaffCar`, even if the method has **nothing** inside and the method isn't even called, one of the menu options which is 'Display all car information', stops working.

If I comment out this method, it starts working again.

The 'Display...' option calls `printCars()`from `Fleet` which has `fleet` loaded with `StaffCar` objects from the serialized file, it's like the existence of this method stops the file from even being read.

Snippet of `Car`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Car implements Serializable
{
    //attributes for Car
    String regNo;
    String model;
    int mileage;

    //default constructor
    public Car() throws CarException
    {
        try 
        {
            setRegNo("??????");
            setModel("Unknown");
            setMileage(0);
        }
        catch (CarException c) 
        {
            System.out.println(c.getMessage());
        }
    }

    //setters
    public void setRegNo(String regNo) throws CarException
    {
        if (regNo.isEmpty())
        {
            throw new CarException("\nInvalid registration number!\n");
        }
        this.regNo = regNo;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) throws CarException
    {
        if (model.isEmpty())
        {
            throw new CarException("\nModel can't be empty!\n");
        }
        this.model = model;
    }

    public void setMileage(int mileage) throws CarException
    {
        if (mileage < 0)
        {
            throw new CarException("\nInvalid mileage!");
        }
        this.mileage = mileage;
    }
}
```

Snippet of `StaffCar`, **where the problem is being caused**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class StaffCar extends Car
{
    String staffName;
    String availability;

    public StaffCar() throws CarException
    {
        super();
        try 
        {
            setAvailability("Available");
            setStaffName("");
        }
        catch (CarException c)
        {
            System.out.println(c.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void setStaffName(String staffName)
    {
        this.staffName = staffName;
    }

    public void setAvailability(String availability) throws CarException
    {
        if (availability != "Available" && availability != "Borrowed")
        {
            throw new CarException("\nInvalid borrow status!\n");
        }
        this.availability = availability;
    }

    //this method causing issues, even if empty
    /*public void returnCar()
    {
    }*/
}
```

Snippet of `Fleet` class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;

public class Fleet 
{
    //declare container
    ArrayList<StaffCar> fleet;
    //container to hold regNos
    ArrayList<String> regNumbers;

    //create constructor
    public Fleet()
    {
        fleet = new ArrayList<StaffCar>();
        regNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    //add method
    public void addCar(StaffCar car)
    {
        fleet.add(car);
        regNumbers.add(car.regNo);
    }

    //print all cars' details
    public void printCars()
    {
        for (StaffCar car:fleet)
        {
            System.out.println(car);
        }
    }

    public void saveAs(String fileName) throws CarException
    {
        FileOutputStream outputFile;

        try
        {
            outputFile = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        }
        catch (IOException io)
        {
            throw new CarException("\nCannot create " + fileName + "\n");
        }

        ObjectOutputStream fleetFile;

        try
        {
            fleetFile = new ObjectOutputStream(outputFile);
            fleetFile.writeObject(regNumbers);
            fleetFile.writeObject(fleet);
            fleetFile.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            throw new CarException("\nCannot create " + fileName + "\n");
        }
        catch (IOException io)
        {
            throw new CarException("\nCannot write " + fileName + "\n");
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "resource" })
    public void open(String fileName) throws CarException
    {
        FileInputStream inputFile;

        try
        {
            inputFile = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            throw new CarException("\nCannot open " + fileName + "\n");
        }

        ObjectInputStream fleetFile;

        try
        {
            fleetFile = new ObjectInputStream(inputFile);
            regNumbers = (ArrayList<String>)fleetFile.readObject();
            fleet = (ArrayList<StaffCar>)fleetFile.readObject();
        }
        catch (IOException io)
        {
            throw new CarException("\nError reading from " + fileName + "\n");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            throw new CarException("\nError reading from " + fileName + "\n");
        }

        try
        {
            fleetFile.close();
        }
        catch (IOException io)
        {
            throw new CarException("\nCannot close " + fileName + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I apologise for what seems like me dumping a bunch of code to you, I know this is bad practice and I have tried to condense the code as much as I can, but I feel like this is all the relevant code to my problem.

Like I said, I don't understand why the simple addition of an **empty** method is causing this issue.

**EDIT**

`Main` class

```
public class Main 
{   
    // new container
    static Fleet fleet = new Fleet();

    // initialise car object
    static StaffCar car;

    // programme loop variable
    static boolean state = false;

    String fileName;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CarException
    {
        start();

        // programme loop
        while (!state) 
        {
            try 
            {
                // menu option variable
                String option;

                //displays menu to user and takes in input
                option = Console.askString("Menu:\n1 Add a car\n2 Display all car information\n3 Find a car\n4 Borrow a car\n5 Return a car\n6 Exit\n\n");
                //removes white spaces
                option = option.trim();

                //switch to handle user request
                switch (option) 
                {
                //if option 1
                case "1":
                    //call static add car method
                    addMethod();
                    break;
                //if option 2
                case "2":
                    //call static print car method
                    displayMethod();
                    break;
                //..option 3
                case "3":
                    //call static find car method
                    findMethod();
                    break;
                //..option 4
                case "4":
                    borrowMethod();
                    break;
                case "5":
                    //returnMethod();
                    break;
                case "6":
                    //call static quit method
                    quitMethod();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println();

                    System.out.println("Invalid option.");

                    System.out.println();
                    break;
                }
            }
            catch (CarException c)
            {
                System.out.println(c.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void start()
        {
            try
            {
                fleet.open("fleet.uwl");
            }
            catch (CarException e)
            {
                //System.out.println("\nFile not created yet!\n");
            }
        }

    //static menu method to print cars
    public static void displayMethod() throws CarException
    {
        System.out.println();

        //call printCars method
        fleet.printCars();

        System.out.println();
     }
```

}

Comment: Hi. it would be worthwhile to have the `switch` code as well from where you are seeing strange behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You saved instances of StaffCar using serialization, then changed the StaffCar class, and are unable to read the saved StaffCar again.

That's because, if you don't specify a serialVersionUID in your class, the JVM computes one for you, based on the layout of the class (fields, methods, etc.). So, to temporarily fix your problem, examine the IOException thrown when reading the file, which should tell you what the serialVersionUID of the saved classes are, and add the following to your class:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = XXXL;
```

where XXX is the serial version UID in the saved objects, which should be mentioned in the exception stack trace.

But really, you have these problems because you chose to use serialization for long term storage, which makes your code very hard to evolve. I wouldn't do that. Instead, I would choose a less fragile and easier to evolve format such as JSON or XML. Define what the file should contain, and generate a JSON/XML document containing this data. Then, whatever your future casses look like, as long as you still can parse JSON/XML, you'll be able to read the files and get the saved data.

Comment: Hi, thank you for telling me this. The issue here is that I have to use serialization for this program, as is it my university assignment. I already know that serialized files are unsafe as well and I would've preferred to use a different save method!